# The static instance of my GameAssets is not instantiating properly | Unity 3D

Tags: class, unity-game-engine, static, instantiation, gameobject

I'm trying to create a static GameAssets class where I can drag into it's references my Prefabs in order to manage every GameObject of my game.

The problem I have here is that when I start the game, the instance of my GameAssets is null (which I don't want) and it's instantiating a clone of GameAssets without the references linked to it.

[Code of the GameAssets class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UTm2.png)

```
public class GameAssets : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static GameAssets _i;

    public static GameAssets i
    {
        get
        {   
            if (_i == null)
                _i =  Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameAssets>("GameAssets"));
            return _i;
        }
    }

    public GameObject ProjectileLaserBall;
}
```

[Hierarchy & Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O67Jc.png)

We can see that I have an empty GameObject called GameAssets with prefabs linked to it's references already!
How can I make Unity understand to use the existing GameAssets instead of creating a clone of it without it's references?

(As asked in my Script, a clone is created)
[Clone of class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG8Zl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around that problem, still it is not solving it.

So instead of including my GameAssets directly into the scene, I leave it in the project folder and assign the references in the prefab GameAssets.
This works as it is creating a clone of GameAssets with the references when I'm calling it.

The problem here is that when I call it from a script, because it is not instantiated, the function doesnt show after GameAssets.i.

And we can't get the instance of a static class with the 'this' keyword so I really don't know how to get this to work properly

Answer (score 0):

In this case as shown in your hierarchy image, you don’t need to create a new instance of your class. You already have an instance in your scene.

As such, when you start the game, you want the static reference to point to the already instantiated class that Unity already created after the scene was loaded.

The code would then look like:

```cs
public class GameAssets : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static GameAssets _i;

    public static GameAssets i
    {
        get
        {   
            if (_i == null)
                _i = this;
            return _i;
        }
    }

    public GameObject ProjectileLaserBall;
}
```

Your code does make use of the `Resources` folder. This make me think that you’ve also got a prefab if this `GameAssets` item in there as well. In this case, maybe your intention was to not define a `GamesAssets` object in your scene, but to load one in at runtime.

With prefabs, you can’t add references to scene objects (in the common sense), but you can add references to other prefabs. So, if you want to do it that way instead, make sure that your `ProjectileLaserBall` is also a prefab, instantiate the `GameAssets` object, add make sure you don’t already have a `GameAssets` object in the scene (as a new one is going to be created). The code for this class would still be the same as I’ve shown above, but you’d instantiate the asset from a different class altogether. If you’ve done everything correctly, you should have a single `GameAssets` item in the hierarchy that can be accessed by `GameAssets.i`

Comment: Alright I understood where my mistake was. To make it work I'll leave the GameAssets object already instantiated and then call it with "this".

I do have a Resources folder with my GameAssets object in it, but my prefabs are in a separated folder. ProjectileLaserBall is indeed a prefab. Thanks a lot anyway